# HTML/CSS Tiles with ajax content under tile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want two rows with four tiles

Each tile loads a specific content, when the user clicks on it. The loaded content should be displayed under the tile, with 100% width of viewport.

Tile of first row is clicked: The content should be displayed under the tile, between the next row...

A tile of the second row is clicked, the content is displayed unter the tile.
[active tile in last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArJT6.jpg)

And this should also work on responsive...
[responsive view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3XMH.jpg)

But I'm not getting the right css for doing the trick. Each tile is at the moment generated with the following markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile portfoliotile-'.$post->ID.'">
<div class="background" style="background-image:URL"></div>
<div class="bluesquare"></div>
<p class="portfoliotitle">get_the_title()</p>
<div id="tileinfo-'.$post->ID.'" class="tileinfo col-md-12 collapse">
<img class="loader-icon spinning-cog" src="loading.svg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.portfoliotile .background {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;

filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-0.5" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-0.5" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="2" intercept="-0.5" /></feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter');
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);
filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; 
-o-transition: all 1s ease; 
transition: all 1s ease;
}
.portfoliotile:hover .background {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)" /* IE 8+ */;
filter: none !important; /* IE 7 and the rest of the world */
-webkit-filter: none !important;
}
.bluesquare {
background: #325975;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0.6;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; 
-o-transition: all 1s ease; 
transition: all 1s ease;
}
.portfoliotile:hover .bluesquare {
background: transparent;
}

.portfoliotitle {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0;
}

.tileinfo {
background: url(../images/bg_tileinfo.jpg) repeat-x;
height: 600px !important;
padding: 100px 0;
width: 100%;
display: none;
border-top: 2px solid #f59c00;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f59c00;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 5s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 5s ease; 
-o-transition: all 5s ease; 
transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you post it on fiddle so we can help you ?

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/u9aqqco0/

Comment: What's your problem exactly ?

Comment: My CSS is not working fine. clicking on a tile does not open the information area with the loaded content... I need help, building the html/css with open/close function. the content is over the tile and the opening area does not work with the columns

Comment: Next try... Has no one any idea or is it not clear enough, what I want to do?